# AngularJS ng-repeat não retorna dados, retorna sempre vazio

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um consulta a uma API que teoricamente está retornando os dados, pelo menos no console me mostra os mesmos. Porém na View com o `ng-repeat` não está trazendo nada.

Abaixo segue o código que estou usando:

**Factory:**

```
pcFactories.factory('TeacherSrv', function ($http) {
    return {
        getAllTeachers: function (TTBId) {
            $http.get('http://xxx.xxx.xxx/' + TTBId)
                .success(function (data) {
                    return data;
                })
                .error(function (status) {
                    return status;
              });
        }
    };
})
```

**Controller**

```
   pcControllers.controller('TeacherCtrl', function ($scope, TeacherSrv) {
        $scope.teachers = TeacherSrv.getAllTeachers(TTBId);
    })
```

**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in teachers" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
   <td>
     <img src="Images/no-photo.png" alt="" />
     <a href="" class="user-link">{{t.TEAName}}</a>
     <span class="user-subhead">{{t.TEAEmail}}</span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Espero que possam me ajudar.

Comment: A primeira coisa que me vem a cabeça é: **Qual o valor de TTBId?**. A segunda é: **De onde TTBId recebe esse valor?**

Comment: TTBId é 1. E por enquanto está sendo carregado de uma variável $scope a fim de executar testes por enquanto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não esta no Angular, e sim no modo como você manipula os resultados retornados pela chamada de API.

A linha `return data;` esta retornando dados dentro da função executada pela `promise`, e não pela `factory`.

Alterando o método `getAllTeachers` para retornar uma `promise`, e manipulando a `promise` dentro do seu controller resolve o problema.

```
pcFactories.factory('TeacherSrv', function ($http) {
    return {
        getAllTeachers: function (TTBId) {
            return $http.get('http://xxx.xxx.xxx/' + TTBId);
        }
    };
});

pcControllers.controller('TeacherCtrl', function ($scope, TeacherSrv) {
    $scope.teachers = null;
    TeacherSrv.getAllTeachers(TTBId).success(function (data) {
        $scope.teachers = data;
    })
    .error(function (status) {
        $scope.teachers = status;
    });
});
```

Tudo isto se deve ao comportamento assíncrono do Javascript, e ao fato de você não estar retornando nada no método `getAllTeachers`.

Observação: você não precisa especificar `http://` na URL no método `get` do serviço `$http`.

Comment: Valeu funcinou, porém agora estou recebendo um Warning conforme a mensagem abaixo: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: A culpa não é deste código que te passei. Algum HTML ou Javascript resultado de um Ajax que você esta executando, executa novas chamadas Ajax enquanto é carregado, o que causa o Warning. Acredito inclusive que este warning pode estar sendo originado em uma chamada jQuery, aonde ele é mais tradicional de ser encontrado. Em todo caso, é um problema diferente do da pergunta original.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o que esteja acontecendo é que quando o ***ng-repeat*** é executado os dados da API ainda nao foram retornados. Dessa forma ***teachers*** ainda esta vazio e o ng-repeat nao vai mostrar nada.

Uma forma de solucionar esse problema é da seguinte forma:

```
pcControllers.controller('TeacherCtrl', function ($scope, TeacherSrv) {
    TeacherSrv.getAllTeachers(TTBId).then(function(result){
       $scope.teachers = result.data;
    });
})
```

O que eu mudei acima foi o seguinte:

- ***TeacherSrv.getAllTeachers(TTBId)*** retorna uma **$promise**, que quando
  finalizada vai atualizar o valor do $scope.teachers. Dessa forma voce
  garante que o seu ng-repeat vai executar como esperado assim que os
  dados da API forem retornados.