# Problemas com XMLHttpRequest AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

tenho um requisição $http.get em minha aplicação conforme pode ser visto em [AngularJS ng-repeat não retorna dados, retorna sempre vazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57324/angularjs-ng-repeat-n%C3%A3o-retorna-dados-retorna-sempre-vazio)

Porém estou recebendo um Warning no console do browser com a seguinte mensagem:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated 
because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

Como posso fazer para resolver?

Comment: Qual o código que causa este warning? Este está sendo exibido pelo Chrome recentemente quando você tenta executar o método `open` de uma XMLHttpRequest com o terceiro parâmetro como `false`, que impede que a requisição seja assíncrona.

Comment: GuilhermeNagatomo, aqui está meu código: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57324/angularjs-ng-repeat-n%C3%A3o-retorna-dados-retorna-sempre-vazio. E sim, está sendo exibido no crhome no momento que acesso a view que faz o acesso aos dados

Comment: Qual versão do Angular você está usando?

Comment: versão 1.3.14 CDN Google

Comment: Olhando rápido pelo fonte do Angular, não parece que o problema seja nele. Haveria algum outro código que se utilize de ajax fora do Angular? O warning não indica no console a linha onde é ativado?

Comment: Não indica nada, apenas a mensagem e faz uma referência ao jquery. Será que é alguma incompatibilidade?

Comment: @JacsonDanerM.Brandão Adicione na sua pergunta as áreas relevantes do seu código e. Este warning geralmente é causado pelo jQuery, portanto, adicione aqui também as áreas relevantes do seu código que fazem uso dele.

Answer (score 1):

Causas possíveis:

- Se o retorno do seu request `$http.get` possuir uma menção a um arquivo javascript, o jQuery (assim como outras bibliotecas) tentará carregar o arquivo mencionado em modo síncrono (já que ele assume que você precisa do arquivo JS para interpretar o conteúdo sendo transmitido.
- Se sua requisição (que na prática se traduz como uma solicitação XMLHttpRequest) estiver sendo executada na *thread* principal e sem a flag indicando uma operação assíncrona - por exemplo, `$.ajax()` com `async: false`.

Soluções: Faça sua requisição em uma *thread* separada, ou utilize a flag `async: true` no jQuery.

Esta mensagem é nativa do browser. O jQuery, por implementar carga síncrona, pode disparar o aviso.