# Tratamento do response do $http.get

Tags: angularjs, http

Olá estou buscando umas informações em um banco de dados local com o seguinte código:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('conexao',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.names = [];
    $http.get('http://localhost/angular/conect/connect.php').then(function successCalback(response){
            $scope.names = response.data;
            console.log($scope.names);
        },
        function errorCallback(response){
            console.error('Erro ' + response);
        });
});
```

Para ser exibido aqui:

```
<body ng-controller="conexao">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
            <td>{{x.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{x.idade}}</td>
            <td>{{x.cor}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Porém tudo que eu consigo é uma tela vazia, embora o console me retorne:

```
>Object {records: Array[2]}
```

E mais essa mensagem:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Quero entender o que está acontecendo e saber como resolver isso.

[image: Print dos Objects:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta vem dentro de um `Object` chamado 'records'. Tente fazer assim:

```
$scope.names = response.data.records;
```

Ou então diretamente em seu `ng-repeat` assim:

```
ng-repeat="x in names.records"
```

---

Quanto a sua outra dúvida, veja [se este tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57370/problemas-com-xmlhttprequest-angularjs) resolve.

Caso não resolva, tente utilizar o seu `$http` deste modo:

```
$http.get('angular/conect/connect.php').then(
    function (response){
        $scope.names = response.data;
        console.log($scope.names);
    },
    function (responseErro){
        console.error('Erro ' + responseErro);
    }
);
```

Comment: Usando essa forma ele retorna: [Object, Object].
Quanto ao outro tópico estou tentando entender as soluções, me parecem meio vagas. lá estão comentando de Jquery e não estou usando nada de Jquery aqui.

Comment: Ok, focando no primeiro problema. Ainda assim você não conseguiu exibir? Coloquei mais uma opção em minha resposta, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Ainda sim não houve resposta.
o 'response.data' retorna: 'Object {records: Array[2]}'
o 'response.data.records' retorna: '[Object, Object]'
Mesmo buscando fazendo o acréscimo de .records no repeat não muda em nada

Comment: Os dados dentro dos 'objects' correspondem corretamente aos que você está tentando exibir? Consegue um print do console com os 'objects' abertos?

Comment: São os dados que eu realmente quero, são os exatos dados que busco do BD. vou por a imagem lá em cima junto à pergunta.

Comment: Note que o seu object possui os campos com a primeira letra maiúscula. Mude isso no seu html também. x.Nome, x.Idade e x.Cor =D

Comment: Funcionou! o.0 kkkkkkk
Sabe me explicar por que acontece isso? eu tenho um outro exemplo que fazer um get de uma API e funciona normalmente, quando passei a usar um .php deu isso, não sei se tem a ver, mas todas as definições que fiz forem em minusculas.

Comment: Ali seria por ser um processo case sensitive, ou seja, se é maiúsculo ou minúsculo, faz diferença. Agora sobre o seu outro problema, vou fornecer um modelo de $http.get que eu utilizo. Acredito que o seu problema esteja acontecendo pois você está passando a `url` completa no processo.

Comment: Não mudou nada com essa alteração no $http.get esse problema ainda persiste. Tudo que estou achando referente a isso envolve Jquery, mas esse não é meu caso, não estou usando Jquery.

Comment: Tudo que estou encontrando é a respeito de jQuery também. Agora estou sem tempo, mas vou ver se consigo uma resposta para você sobre isso.